# Consistency of estimators (linear regression)

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

I need to show that (in a linear regression model under assumptions MLR1 - MLR5), $$\tilde\beta_1 = (\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100} x_ix_i')^{-1} *( \frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100} x_iy_i)$$, assuming $n > 100 $,
is inconsistent. (I don't know if WLLN is applicable here since there is no $n$)

I also need to show that, $$\tilde\beta_2 = (\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_ix_i')^{-1} *( \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_iy_i)$$ ,assuming that $n$ is even,
is consistent. (I think that I can use WLLN in this case but I am not sure.)

I do not know how to prove the statements, please help!

Comment: You need to include the self study tag.

Comment: Also, check its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and update the question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tilde{\beta}_1$ is the OLS estimator using only the first 100 observations. $\tilde{\beta}_2$ is the OLS estimator using the first $n/2$ observations, which can also be written as

$\tilde{\beta}_2=(\frac{1}{n/2} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_i x_i')^{-1} * (\frac{1}{n/2} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_i y_i)$

Of course $n \to \infty$ implies $\frac{n}{2} \to \infty$, so the proof of consistency for $\tilde{\beta}_2$ is to invoke the consistency of standard OLS. This argument can be formalized using the [definition of the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_limits_at_infinity).

Proving inconsistency for $\tilde{\beta}_1$ can be done by finding any counterexample. One option is to assume

$y_i=0*x_i+\varepsilon_i$

so $\beta=0$. Assume $x_i=1$ for all observations (a constant regressor). Assume $\varepsilon_i=\text{N}(0,1)$ iid. Then $\tilde{\beta}_1=\frac{1}{100}\sum_i \varepsilon_i$. Consistency means that for any $\delta>0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr(|\tilde{\beta}_1-\beta|>\delta)=0$, but here the limit distribution of $\tilde{\beta}_1$ is the same as the distribution at $n=100$. So you can just show

$\Pr(\frac{1}{100}\sum_i \varepsilon_i>\delta) > 0$

where $\frac{1}{100}\sum_i \varepsilon_i \sim \text{N}(0,\frac{1}{100})$

Comment: +1 Very clearly reasoned, thank you.  Welcome to our site!